# Citibike data downlaod

Tags: python, web-scraping

gurus

I tried to extract urls on citibike data page and download those zip files. However, the following code returned null. Can someone give some hints? Thanks for your help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

Comment: There's a bunch of operations there but you don't describe which of them doesn't behave as expected and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requested page is actually "empty" (contains no links). Required links comes from another URL in XML format.

You can try below to get required output:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata')
source = etree.fromstring(r.content)

for item in source.xpath('//*'):
    if item.text and item.text.endswith('zip'):
        print('https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/' + item.text)
```